I need help to correct my proof of the inverse of $a+1\in R$, with $R$ a ring
In a question of Paulo Aluffi's Notes from the Underground, there is the following question:

An element a in a ring R is niloptent if $a^k=0$ for some $k\ge 1$. Prove that if $a$ is nilpotent, then $1+a$ is invertible.

That is to say there exists some $b\in R$ such that $(1+a)b = b(1+a) = 1_R$.
Here is my (incorrect) proof:
Let $k$ be the smallest integer such that $a^k=0$.
Then, we can construct the following system of equations:
$$
\begin{align}
1_R+a+a^2+...+a^{k-1} &= c\in R\\
a+a^2+...+a^{k-1} &= ac\\
...&\\
a^{k-1} = a^{k-1}c
\end{align}
$$
Thus, $0_R = a^{k-1}(c-1_R)$, which implies that either $c=1_R$ (trivial), or $c-1_R = a \implies c = a+1_R$.
If we use this last possible $c$, and subtract the 2nd line of the system of equations from the 1st, then we find $$1_R = c-ac = (1-a)c = (1-a)(a+1_R)$$
We can do the same to find the same right inverse.
Unfortunately, the inverse given by Allufi is $(1-a+a^2-a^3+...+(-1)^{k-1}a^{k-1})$. How is my answer wrong?
Thank you all for the help!

This question is similar to: Finding the inverse of $I+N$ where $N$ is nilpotent. As for your mistake, Mark's comment is sufficient.

@AnneBauval It is different. OP didn't ask how to prove the statement.

I know, whence my edit of the comment.

It's good to develop the skill of being able to find the flaw in your own reasoning. When a sequence of equations leads you to an incorrect conclusion, you know there is some step along the way that is incorrect, you just need to find which one. If you are unable to find any flaw, try specific examples. I would start with an explicit example of a nilpotent element of a ring and follow every step of your logic until you find the specific flaw. Upper-triangular matrices with zeroes on the diagonal give you examples of nilpotent elements of a ring so you could start there.

For a solution-verification question to be on topic you must specify precisely which step in the proof you question, and why so. This site is not meant to be used as a proof checking machine.

It's not true that if  $,a^k=0,$ then $,a^{k-1}x = 0,\Rightarrow,x=0,$ or $,x=a,,$ e.g. $,x = ab,$ is  a root, for all $,b.\ \ $

Please do not answer in the comments.
